# how can i get my 'Scroll to top'- button to work

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my code. I cannot see to get my **scroll to top**-button to work.

I tried several things and none have worked so far

```js
// Get the button:
let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

```html
<div style="height:700px">Content</div>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Go to top <span class="arrow">&#8593;</span></button>
```

Comment: which part doesn't work? display/hide the button, or scrolling to top?

Comment: The show works in Chrome if the height before it button is taller than 500 px. The scroll to top also works

Comment: Consider using [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the button:
let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function topFunction() {
    window.scrollTo({top : 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
 }

function scrollFunction() {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (pos > 20 ) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

```css
body{
min-height: 500px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  background-color: green; /* Set a background color */
  color: white; /* Text color */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
  border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>go to top</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>go to top</h1>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn">^</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function topFunction() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 }

function scrollFunction() {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (pos > 20 ) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor